# rotation of a line to the $y$ axis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, linear-transformations

for the line, $4x -3y = 0$, find the matrix for a counterclockwise rotation taking the line $4x-3y=0$ to the $y$-axis.

I have no idea what this question is even asking. Is it asking for a matrix that would rotate the line parallel to the $y$ axis?

If so, how do I go about doing that? I can see that it is a pythagorean triple line, and I can sort of see how those numbers $(3,4,5)$ could be used to get the answer, but after that I'm lost.

Comment: The 2-by-2 matrix has a standard form involving cos(theta) and sin(theta).  You need to find the theta.  This can be deduced from the fact that theta is 90 degrees minus the angle producing the (3,4,5) triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to find the matrix.

Probably the easiest way is to observe that all rotation matrix are of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix},$$

where $\theta$ is angle that you want to turn (counter-clockwisely). Thus you need only to find the angle between that line and the $y$-axis.

Comment: John, that matrix does clockwise rotation.  The minus sign should be in the upper right hand entry.

Comment: Thanks, edited @SinisterCutlass